# Case Studies of high profile hacks

Tags: appsec, attacks, exploit, known-vulnerabilities

Every hack happens because of a form of security vulnerability or another, and I feel that the best way to avoid/fix these vulnerabilities is to learn about them.

Is there anywhere on the internet where I can find case studies of high profile hacks? For high profile hacks, media outlets usually publish uneducated information regarding the hack, usually far from what actually happened.

Case studies that include information like how did the hack happen, what vulnerability in the system allowed the hackers in, etc, will be really useful in preventing the same hack from happening again.

Comment: On this websites you can find some in-depth information, but it's not exactly what you're asking for: https://www.alienvault.com/open-threat-exchange/blog